# for loop function in Seurat analysis in R

Tags: r, for-loop, marker, seurat

I have tried to get multiple outputs of the function I made

```
ratio_marker_out_2 = function(marker_gene, cluster_id){
marker_gene = list(row.names(FindMarkers(glioblastoma, ident.1 = cluster_id)))
for (gene in marker_gene){
all_cells_all_markers = glioblastoma@assays$RNA@counts[gene,]
selected_cells_all_marker = all_cells_all_markers[cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]
gene_count_out_cluster = glioblastoma@assays$RNA@counts[,cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)] 
ratio_out = sum(selected_cells_all_marker)/sum(gene_count_out_cluster) 
} 
return(ratio_out)
}
```

Here, the length of marker_gene is about hundreds. Let's say the length is 100. I want to get ratio_out of each gene in marker_gene. However, when running this function, I only get one output instead of a list of 100 ratio_out. Could please anyone helps how to fix it?

The output I got for

```
ratio_marker_out_2(marker_gene, 0)
```

is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HKCz.png) 0.5354895. Please see the pict below [image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be that [sum](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sum) built-in function.

By default, it returns a number. So when you do:

```
ratio_out = sum(selected_cells_all_marker)/sum(gene_count_out_cluster)
```

you're actually dividing two numerics.

So if you want to return a list, you must divide, depending on your calculations, just

```
ratio_out = (selected_cells_all_marker)/sum(gene_count_out_cluster)
```

Comment: It is correct. I tried it and it shows a list. However, there is a problem in selected_cell_all_markers. I want it to show gene counts across all cells except cells in cluster_id, and it should be a data frame with #gene (1913) x #cells outside cluster_id.(less than the total number of cells which is 1234) But what I have is a data frame with 1,949,347 x 1. Any idea please?

Comment: I'm not sure. I can't figure out anything. But I see that `all_cells_all_markers[cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]` but I wonder if it could be `all_cells_all_markers[cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma), ]` or `all_cells_all_markers[, cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]`?

Comment: I fix it already. I use all_cells_all_markers[marker_gene, cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)] and ratio_out = (selected_cells_all_marker)/sum(gene_count_out_cluster).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using

```
all_cells_all_markers[marker_gene, cluster_id!=Idents(glioblastoma)]
ratio_out = (selected_cells_all_marker)/sum(gene_count_out_cluster).
```